# How to find my Reputation Limit per day

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I know that there is a reputation limit per day, but how is my reputation limit calculated or is there anywhere that I can find that limit for me?

Once reputation increase stopped for me at 345 and another day it stopped at 320, so I am confused!

Comment: It's 200, accepts and bounties are not included though, see [How does Reputation work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on MSE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cap is 200 points, every day. However, *accepts* and *bounty awards* are not subject to the cap.

So, up-votes can take you up to 200 points, after which they no longer award reputation points. If you received a down vote that takes you below 200 again, another up-vote after that gets you +2 again as the reputation is capped at 200 once again.

But since the +15 from an accept and bounty awards don't count against the cap at all, your total reputation gained in a day can vary widely, based on how many of your answers were marked as accepted or how much bounty you were awarded.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for the nitty gritty details.

Comment: Is it applicable to all the users

Comment: @NoDisplayName: it is applicable to all users. You, me, Jon Skeet, everyone.

Comment: So if you hit the limit and get downvoted, you don't automatically earn more rep from upvotes that didn't get any rep (or full rep) due to the limit?

Comment: @dbush: you won't, no. The cap does not make you entirely immune from downvotes.